# Is it allowed to handle money transactions within Android app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I haven't found a solid answer to this on either the documentation of android/google play, SO, or on google searches.

In iOS is it not allowed to handle money transactions within the app, making you only do in-app purchases. I want to know if in Android this is the same case.
I know Android does not have a review process like iOS so this will be harder to "catch" even if its not allowed, but I wanted to do it correctly from the start.

The documentation suggests to do in-app purchases, but they take a 30% of the sale. Also, this seems to only be a suggestion.

So, here's the direct question. Can I sell images inside my app, handle the credit card transaction, handle the billing and charge the amount of money within my app in Android, without having to give 30% of the sale to google, and without having to use in-app purchases? I have seen apps like the Amazon Kindle app do this, but I don't know if they have to report/share 30% of the sale in the background.

Hopefully this isn't off topic since its a developing-related question, even though its not about specific code.

Edit: Just to clarify. The "goods" to be purchased in the app would be images, which can then be edited within the app and printed from within the app to a printer. The images will be downloaded from the app as an encrypted file so they can only be used with this app.

Comment: Read the policy. You need to decide whether the images you're selling count as "virtual goods".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of distribution channels, not programming.

Comment: Is there any other place (website, not lawyers) where I could ask this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! If the images that are being sold, once purchased, are available outside the app. According to [Google Play Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html) :

> Developers offering virtual goods or currencies within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.
>
> Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except:
>
> - where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription); or
> - where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can be played on other music players).

Comment: Hmm, that's tricky. I don't think an image counts as a virtual good - unless it is only accessibly from within the app.

Comment: @iheanyi You mean, the images you want to sell can be viewed from outside the app?

Comment: I mean that if the images that are being sold, once purchased are available outside the app, then it is not a virtual good. It's like buying a video game through the app and then getting a link to download the executable. That the app is used to deliver the image, rather than some source external to the app, does not change the virtual-ness (or lack thereof) of the product.

Comment: I updated the question with what my goods are and what you'll do with them. The "goods" to be purchased in the app would be images, which can then be edited within the app and printed from within the app to a printer.
Sounds like this falls into the in-app option :(